# How to have multiple types of users in separated tables?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm building a project in which I'll have 3 types of users.

Super Admin
Teacher
Student

Teacher and Student will be in a table called Class, each Class will have one teacher and several Student.

As far as I know(Very limited), Django only provide one user table for all kinds of users, But I don't know how to go on, because I will need separated tables to keep the data organized and without redudance, in addition to relate with other tables.

Is there any kind of solution to solve this problem ?

Comment: FYI please avoid python reserved words such as `Class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement **related_name** attributes something similar to this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ClassRoom(models.Model):
    # One classroom one teacher
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="teacher")
    # One classroom many students
    student = models.ManytoManyField(User, blank=True, null=True,
                                     related_name="students")
    .....
```

Also refer to these links for more info:

[Django teacher students easy solution. Use separate tables, or permissions and groups? How? Other ideas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494481/django-teacher-students-easy-solution-use-separate-tables-or-permissions-and-g)

[Django model with Foreign Key and ManyToMany relations to same model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390901/django-model-with-foreign-key-and-manytomany-relations-to-same-model)

[Two sets of users (teacher and student) in Django authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033067/two-sets-of-users-teacher-and-student-in-django-authentication)

Comment: Thanks man, I think that will do, could you please show how the UserManager would be ?